# Instant Articles not showing up once posted to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I have encountered an error where i post Instant Articles via the php Api.
It works since sometimes it pops up, but more often than not it doesn't.

The JSON response from the api call is a id, assuming it is the ID for the article.

Anyone who have encountered the same issue? No errors to log whatsoever, the ID is like a receipt for the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

From their resource page:

> However — and this is important to understand — publishing an Instant Article does not automatically create a new post on your Facebook Page. Instead, new Instant Articles are added to the Instant Articles library associated with your Page. To add a post on your Facebook Page, you must still compose and publish a post to your Page. Automated publishing of Instant Articles vis RSS or API simply means that whenever enabled readers encounter the URL of your article while using Facebook, the article will be rendered as an Instant Article.

Comment: Thanks!
Im looking in the Instant Articles Library that indeed is associated with my page. And it is empty. That is my issue

Comment: It also mentions that you have to submit 10 articles before they will review them to make sure your formatting is acceptable. Dunno if that's the case or not with you, but I thought I'd throw that in there as well.

Comment: Yeah, correct, i can see afew in the library, but i've posted 90, and 3 of them are showing. As mentioned earlier i do get a return on each post-call via the api, and a http-code 200?? Should be 201 for creation?

Comment: Huh, according to their own documentation, the response only includes the import-status-id which you can then use to check the import status. It doesn't mean that the article has been imported, just that they've gotten the article, and here's the id to check it's import status.

[link]https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/api

Comment: You sir, are a life saver. Thank you very much! Take care